# CoreData openWithCompletionHandler How do you wait for it to finish before moving on

Tags: ios5, ios6, xcode4.5

I'm trying to get CoreData to work, so I've made myself a little test app.  Everything works properly, except for 1 type of item - open(or save or close)WithCompletionHandler.  I would like the handler to finish before anything else can happen.  In lieu of putting all of the code here, I'm just putting where the problem occurs.  I have been trying to get this WithCompletionHandler to work for quite some time, and I just can't seem to get my head around how to make the rest of the code wait until the completion handler is finished.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.contactsDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success)
    {
        if (success)
            [self loadArrayFromFile];
    }
}

-(IBAction)deleteButton:(id)sender
{
    // I need this to NOT work until open is finished (or a previous save is finished)
    // delete an item in the database
    [self saveDatabase];
}

-(IBAction)addButton:(id)sender
{ 
    // I need this to NOT work until open is finished (or a previous save is finished)
    // add an item to the database
    [self saveDatabase];
}
```

On the device, if you hit the add or delete button 10 times in a row, it crashes.  Also, when it first loads up, you can add before the database is loaded, and it creates a mistake.